# How to replace item in a list with a different character at multiple indices?

Tags: list

Let’s say I have a list of letters. How do I replace an item in the list with something else at multiple indices. The index locations of interest are stored in another list.

```
wordsplit = ["d", "o", "g"]
underscoresplit = ["_", "_", "_",]

Guess = input("> ")

indices = []
for i in range(len(wordsplit)):
    if wordsplit[i] == Guess:
        indices.append(i)

#if I input "d" into Guess, and it is in wordsplit, I want to replace an 
underscore in underscoresplit with "d" at the indexes it appears in wordsplit. Final result that I want: "d__".
I tried storing the index locations in the indices list above.
```

Comment: can you include an example to show what you want?

Comment: @VishalSingh Just added one.

Comment: @VishalSingh I want to get: "d__". Those are two underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use list comprehension to replace the item present at the given `indices`.

```
underscoresplit = [
    wordsplit[i] if i in indices else c for i, c in enumerate(underscoresplit)
]
```

Also, you can collect indices using list comprehension instead of for loop. It is more pythonic this way.

```
indices = [index for index, word in enumerate(wordsplit) if word == Guess]
```

Comment: Thank you. You helped me out a ton.